# Different Persistence when testing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ant, junit

I would like to use a different Persistence Unit when testing with JUnit. I create an embedded EJBContainer and lookup my Enterprise Bean, but of course it uses the Persistence Unit that is described in the PersistenceContext-annotation in my Enterprise Bean.

Is there a way to achieve my goal? As I found similar questions, I should mention, that I use Ant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) for that. While packing the test archive, you can include any file you like as the test's `persistence.xml`:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Deployment
        public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {
            return ShrinkWrap
                    .create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                    ...
                    .addAsResource("MY_TEST_RESOURCES/persistence.xml",
                            "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                    ...
        }
```

EDIT: I have simply assumed reasonable Ant integration for Arquillian, but I was wrong.  Though the makers of Arquillian announce that it is not tied to maven and supposedly

> ...works just as well—if not better—when used in a project with an
>   Ant or Gradle

as stated [here](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/). There is no working example provided for ant. The relevant [documentation page](http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/reference/snapshot/en-US/html/build.integration.html) is unfinished. There are some related scraps [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/622214) and [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/160986?_sscc=t)  and an article [here](http://jdevelopment.nl/integration-testing-arquillian-maven/), so some people have got it working.

I hope you can work from there. Do post and accept your own solution once you get it to work.

Comment: This would be a nice solution, but unfortunately, Arquillian and Ant do not seem to get along very well, at least I fail to find any resource on how to add Arquillian to my project as there seems to be no complete Arquillian jar.

Comment: @DominikKaisers you are right, unfortunately. Have edited the answer to be a little bit less unhelpful :) Good luck.

Comment: In the end, what I did, was to test my DAO's logic outside the container. I create the DAO with 'new' and simply set the EntityManager manually through an EntityManagerFactory - configured to use my Test-PersistenceUnit (both in the same persistence.xml for now, but I'm still trying to separate them).

This was sufficient for me to test my DAO's logic.

Comment: @DominikKaisers As long as you do not rely on container managed transactions (CMT) and the tests are small and unit-test-like, this can be enough - you can control the TX from your test. If you want to test whole service calls, i.e. EJB chains relying on CMT, this approach quickly turns ugly to impossible. Unfortunately I am not aware of a better testing strategy with Ant.